# Cakephp 3.0 REST API add conditions in API response

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Can we set conditions in xml response. Like there is status fields in database that is in numeric like 0,1,2,3 and we want to show it like below

```
0 for => Complete
2 for => Cancelled
2 for => Return
5 for => Refund.
```

How can we add a new fields in xml response if the fields does not exist in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose you are fetching the sales report from Sales table in Cakephp 3.0 Using rest API. 
If you want to customize, rename, add few fields in response of Rest API You can do it like below

REST API URL will be something like below

```
https://example.com/api/index.json?fromdate_utc=2016-10-03&todate_utc=2016-10-03
```

And functino in controller be something like below:-

```
 public function index($fromdate = null, $todate = null)
    {
        //set date range for 
        if(!empty($_GET['fromdate_utc']) && !empty($_GET['todate_utc'])){
            // if from amd to date are same add +1 day in to date to get result 
            $to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['todate_utc'] . ' +1 day'));
            $dateRage = array('Sales.SalesDate >= ' => $_GET['fromdate_utc'], 'Sales.SalesDate <=' => $to_date);
        }else{
            $dateRage = array();                    
        }

        $conditions = array(
            'and' => array($dateRage),
        );

        //$this->Auth->allow();
        $sales = $this->Sales->find('all', array(
                        'conditions' => $conditions
                    ))
                    ->select(['SalesNo', 'SalesDate', 'TotalValue', 'TotalDiscount', 'NetTotal', 'PaymentMode', 'Status'])
                    ->where(['StoreId' => '8','Status  !=' => '2','Status  !=' => '4'])->andWhere(['Status !=' => 1])->andWhere(['Status !=' => 4]);
                    //->limit(3);
        $salesResponse = array();
        //echo '<br/>Count no of output => '.$sales->count();
        if($sales->count() >0 ){
            foreach($sales as $key=>$salesData){
                //re generate the array as per your requirements
                $salesResponse[$key]['SalesNo']         = $salesData->SalesNo;
                $salesResponse[$key]['SalesDate']   = $salesData->SalesDate;
                $salesResponse[$key]['TotalValue']      = $salesData->TotalValue;
                $salesResponse[$key]['TotalDiscount']   = $salesData->TotalDiscount;
                $salesResponse[$key]['NetTotal']        = $salesData->NetTotal;
                $salesResponse[$key]['SaleTax']         = 0; // add new fields that does not exist in database
                $salesResponse[$key]['PaymentMode']     = $salesData->PaymentMode;
                // change the status from numeric to character and pass it to response
                if($salesData->Status == 5){
                    $salesResponse[$key]['Status']      = 'Refund';
                }elseif($salesData->Status == 3){
                    $salesResponse[$key]['Status']      = 'Return';
                }elseif($salesData->Status == 2){
                    $salesResponse[$key]['Status']      = 'Cancelled';
                }elseif($salesData->Status == 0){
                    $salesResponse[$key]['Status']      = 'Complete';
                }
            }
        }else{
            $salesResponse = array('Error ! sorry not found any record.');
        }

        $this->set([
            'sales' => $salesResponse,
            '_serialize' => ['sales']
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with having a slightly different name for the status in the XML, you could create a virtual field called, for example, status_text. Add a `protected function _getStatusText` in your Sale entity class which returns the desired text based on the status integer, and also add `protected $_virtual = ['status_text'];` to the Sale class, and you should start getting the status text in your XML.

Comment: Greg its the same thing we can create a protected function inside Sales class that will return the status text. Above i do not create separate function  i just add conditions in the same functions. Its also working fine.

Comment: Your solution should work fine. It just looks a bit fragile to me, as it needs to be updated any time you add a new field to the table.

Comment: Greg  Definitely if there will add any new field in table we should need to add that fields in controller and in model also. I hope its fine,  Is there any other solution to add new fields in table without adding that fields in model as well as in controller ?

Comment: You'll generally need to add them somewhere (validation, for example), but my philosophy is to minimize such work. Your method here means one more place to add them; my virtual field suggestion avoids this one.

Comment: Greg Schmidt yes it may be helpful but i did not use it before now i will use virtual fields in my next projects. Than you for your suggestion.